# MySQL Combine multiple rows

Tags: sql, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have a table similar to the following (of course with more rows and fields):

```
category_id | client_id | date        | step
     1            1       2009-12-15    first_step
     1            1       2010-02-03    last_step

     1            2       2009-04-05    first_step
     1            2       2009-08-07    last_step
     
     2            3       2009-11-22    first_step
     
     3            4       2009-11-14    first_step
     3            4       2010-05-09    last_step
```

I would like to transform this so that I can calculate the time between the first and last steps and eventually find the average time between first and last steps, etc. Basically, I'm stumped at how to transform the above table into something like:

```
category_id | first_date | last_date
     1        2009-12-15   2010-02-03
     1        2009-04-05   2009-08-07
     2        2009-11-22   NULL
     3        2009-11-14   2010-05-09
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Updated based on question update/clarification:

```
  SELECT t.category_id,
         MIN(t.date) AS first_date,
         CASE 
           WHEN MAX(t.date) = MIN(t.date) THEN NULL 
           ELSE MAX(t.date)
         END AS last_date
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.category_id, t.client_id
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified my example, so I've changed it. There are many entries per category.

Comment: Ok, as long as I change the GROUP BY clause to: GROUP BY t.category_id, t.client_id this works.

Comment: Actually, I just realized it doesn't flag the last_date as NULL when there is no last_date.

Comment: @Mitchell: Right - sorry about that, fixed.

Comment: You're on the right track. How about the following? It has the advantage that if min and max date are actually both the same, then last_date will be filled in.

SELECT t.category_id,
         MIN(t.date) AS first_date,
         IF ((COUNT(*) = 2), MAX(t.date), NULL) AS last_date
    FROM TABLE t
GROUP BY t.category_id, t.client_id

Comment: @Mitchell: I try to use ANSI notation to keep queries as portable as possible, but I do think your COUNT should be: `IF ((COUNT(*) >= 2)...` to catch if you have more than one entry per category & client.  I don't think there's a difference in the explain plan otherwise between your and my queries.

Comment: Although in my particular case in can never be > 2, I think you're right that >= 2 is the better general solution. What part of the query is not ANSI compatible?

Comment: @Mitchell: I see - The `IF` isn't - CASE expressions are ANSI.  I really prefer CASE/SWITCH statements over IF syntax any day...

Comment: I didn't realize IF statements are not ANSI. Coming from a language programming background, IF statements are pretty universal. I've added the solution with the CASE statement. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: @Mitchell: CASE may seem overkill for a simple IF, but it accommodate multiple IF/ELSE more elegantly.  Oracle's DECODE is ugly at first glance in comparison...

Answer (score 1):

a simple `GROUP BY` should do the trick

```
SELECT   category_id
         , MIN(first_date)
         , MAX(last_date)
    FROM TABLE
GROUP BY category_ID
```

Comment: Yes, as long as I change the GROUP BY clause to: GROUP BY category_id, client_id this works.

Comment: I just realized it doesn't flag the last_date as NULL when there is no last_date.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select
    category_id
    , min(date) as first_date
    , max(date) as last_date
from
    table_name
group by
    category_id
    , client_id
```

Comment: I may have oversimplified my example, so I've changed it. There are many entries per category.

Comment: Yes, as long as I change the GROUP BY clause to: GROUP BY category_id, client_id this works.

Comment: I just realized it doesn't flag the last_date as NULL when there is no last_date.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer:

```
  SELECT fist.category_id, first.date, last.date
    FROM tableName first
    LEFT JOIN tableName last
        ON first.category_id = last.category_id
        AND first.step = 'first_step'
        AND last.step ='last_step'
```

You could also do the calculations in the query instead of just returning the two date values.

Comment: This will actually give every combination of dates for each category out there.

Comment: You are right...thats what I get for going too fast.  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: Just looked and another column has been added (client_id) so this query would not work with that change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two sub queries and then join them together - something like the following

select
 *
from 
    (select 
        *,
        date as first_date
    from 
        table
    where step = "first_step") a
    left join ( select 
                    * 
                    date as last_date
                from 
                    table
                where step = "lastt_step") b
    on (a.category_id = b.category_id)

Enjoy!

Comment: I just tried it and like kniemczak's answer, I think it gives every combination of dates.